# Nested arrays in C# like in php

Tags: c#, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make an array with arrays inside, which can contain even more arrays or straight strings. In php I would do:

```
chords = new array
    (
        array(
            array("G","D"),
            "C",
            array("G","D"),
            "Am",
        ),
        array(
            "Am",
            "C",
            "Am",
            "C",
        ),
    );
```

I was wondering what's the most efficient way to accomplish this in C#. Should I use Lists, or multidimensional string[,,] array, or is there a yet more efficient way to accomplish this?

I have tried Lists but found it rather annoying to work with when you have a `List<List<List<String>>>`. Multidimensional arrays gave me some kind of error and I generally dislike working with them anyway.

Thank you

Comment: C# is statically typed, so you do *not* want to create such arrays. You want to have a *typed* data structure.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about doing this for my goals?

Comment: Create a class to hold the data; take a course on C#, learn the language.

Comment: @poke An array of string is strongly typed

Comment: @DvS OP is using an array of potentially strings or arrays of strings…

Comment: I hadn't really considered using a custom made class, I got it working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same kind of thing in C#:

```
string[][] chords = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "G","D" },
    new string[] { "C" },
    new string[] { "Am", "C" }

};
```

But as pointed out by @poke, .NET is strongly typed so you can't willy nilly have a string array of strings or string arrays. A jagged array is an array of arrays.